Azure OpenAI assistants API: Invalid parameter: 'response_format' of type 'json_schema' is not supported with model version `gpt-4o-08-06`
I have deployed GPT 4o 2024-08-06 in Sweden Central called gpt-4o-08-06. I am using the assistants API and making this call (Output is a pydantic model):
run = ai_client.beta.threads.runs.create_and_poll(
        thread_id=thread_id,
        assistant_id=my_assistant_id,
        model="gpt-4o-08-06",
        response_format={
            "type": "json_schema",
            "json_schema": {"name": "output", "schema": Output.model_json_schema()},
        },
    )

This gives the following error response from the API:
'error': {'message': "Invalid parameter: 'response_format' of type 'json_schema' is not supported with model version `gpt-4o-08-06`.", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': 'response_format', 'code': None}}

Same thing happens for mini. The Azure OpenAI documentation says it should be available. Can you test it and get it to work?
